# Change/remove global method signatures or variables

Tags: global-variables, global-methods

I want to remove an unused custom sobject in my managed package, but it's part of a global method signature. Is it possible to remove the global method from the managed package or change the method signature to reference another object?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [@deprecated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_deprecated.htm):

```
@deprecated
 global void myMethod(String a) {

 }
```

A deprecated item, such as a method or a class, can still be referenced internally by the package developer

Comment: I've already tried that and it doesn't work. Salesforce complained about the deprecated method referencing the sobject that I want to delete from my managed package.

Comment: you need to raise case with sales force for component deletion and you need to consider about subscriber org too.